# Android SugarRecord is trying to work with a table that doesn't exist

Tags: android, sugarorm

Running my code, I get this error.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: STORE (code
>   1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO STORE(TOTAL_TEXT......

I have read some forums and I still don't have any idea of why the system looks for this ***STORE*** table. In any part of the code, there is no referment to any ***STORE*** table because it doesn't exist in my Cloud FireBase. The table that I have is called ***Stores***.

One of the most popular solution is to disable Instant Run but I can't because I need it for the rest of the code.

Going throw Logcat, I see that the issue is due to `SugarRecord.save(store);` of `FirebaseDatabaseHelper.java`.

My code is this.

**FirebaseDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public static void getAllStores(final StoresSyncedListener storesSyncedListener)
    {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        log("getAllStores");
        db.collection("Stores")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task)
                    {
                        log("task.toString " + task.toString());
                        log("task.isSuccessful " + task.isSuccessful());
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            log("task.getResult " + task.getResult().size());
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult())
                            {
                                Store store = document.toObject(Store.class);
                                store.setStoreId(document.getId());
                                //save all stores to local Sugar database
                                SugarRecord.save(store);
                            }
                            log("task.SugarRecord.saveInTx B");

                            storesSyncedListener.onStoresSynced(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            storesSyncedListener.onStoresSynced(false);
                            logError("Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Store.java**

```
public class Store extends SugarRecord
{
    @Unique
    private String storeId;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String postalCode;
    private String taxCode;
    private String name;
    private float totalXpoint;
    private String priceSeparator;
    private String totalText;
    private String dateFormat;
    private String currency;

    public Store()
    {
        super();
    }

    public String getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    private String owner;


    public String getStoreId()
    {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(String storeId)
    {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getMail()
    {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail)
    {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getPhone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone)
    {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPostalCode()
    {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode)
    {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getTaxCode()
    {
        return taxCode;
    }

    public void setTaxCode(String taxCode)
    {
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getTotalXpoint()
    {
        return totalXpoint;
    }

    public void setTotalXpoint(float totalXpoint)
    {
        this.totalXpoint = totalXpoint;
    }

    public String getPriceSeparator()
    {
        return priceSeparator;
    }

    public void setPriceSeparator(String priceSeparator)
    {
        this.priceSeparator = priceSeparator;
    }

    public String getTotalText()
    {
        return totalText;
    }

    public void setTotalText(String totalText)
    {
        this.totalText = totalText;
    }

    public String getDateFormat()
    {
        return dateFormat;
    }

    public void setDateFormat(String dateFormat)
    {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    public String getCurrency()
    {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency)
    {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Stores{" +
                "storeId='" + storeId + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", mail='" + mail + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", postalCode='" + postalCode + '\'' +
                ", taxCode='" + taxCode + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", totalXpoint=" + totalXpoint +
                ", priceSeparator='" + priceSeparator + '\'' +
                ", totalText='" + totalText + '\'' +
                ", dateFormat='" + dateFormat + '\'' +
                ", currency='" + currency + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
11-17 16:24:43.580 9133-9133/com.example.ves.gennaio3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ves.gennaio3, PID: 9133
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: STORE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO STORE(TOTAL_TEXT,ADDRESS,MAIL,TOTAL_XPOINT,PHONE,CURRENCY,CITY,OWNER,DATE_FORMAT,ID,NAME,PRICE_SEPARATOR,POSTAL_CODE,TAX_CODE,STORE_ID,COUNTRY) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:280)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:260)
        at com.example.ves.gennaio3.firebase.FirebaseDatabaseHelper$8.onComplete(FirebaseDatabaseHelper.java:198)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: I had the same issue and the only help come to save was disabling Insta run as the lib SugarRecord have issues with Insta run feature which yet not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

it does not really matter how the remote node on Firebase is being called ...you have to rename the local table `Stores` to `STORE` - as it is being expected by the `ORM`'s naming conventions. have checked the [documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/), but there are no annotations available for mapping table names - as they would exist for [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). but when looking at the [source code](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar) there seems to be a [@Table](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/annotation/Table.java) annotation, which possibly would permit the mapping:

```
@table(name = "Stores")
public class Store extends SugarRecord<Store> {

}
```